# How to create an automator workflow/application to delete jpeg when raw exist

Tags: terminal, applescript, photos, automator

I have approx 1 terabyte of Canon CR2 images in 40 sub-folders, some with matching jpeg and some just jpeg.

I want to delete all jpegs that have a matching corresponding raw .cr2 file.

I would like to mac automator or a script to run through terminal.

I tried some scripts found on photos.stackexchange.com but I get syntax errors when I try to run it.

I get an error `Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "*.CR2" suffix

find . -type f -iname "*.${suffix}" | \
while read line
do
  lowercase=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/${suffix}/jpg/gi")
  uppercase=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/${suffix}/JPG/gi")

  if [ -f "${lowercase}" ]
  then
    rm -v "${lowercase}"
  elif [ -f "${uppercase}" ]
  then
    rm -v "${uppercase}"
  else
    echo "${line}: no jpg present"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Can you add `echo $line` as the first line of the loop to show the filenames? Most likely one of them contains characters confusing the shell.

Comment: If you copy/pasted the script, you may have a bad " in there.